# Crystal Reports line spacing is different for the same report in multiple environments?

Tags: crystal-reports

This is an excerpt from my printed report. It's the **same file**, printed from two different development environments. Both were aligned with the bottom, so the text should match. However, the one on the **RIGHT** has the correct spacing, so that everything prints on one page. The one on the **LEFT** has increased spacing, and the end of the document is cut off.

[image: Incorrect spacing]

What could be the cause of this? How would I fix it? The one on the right is Crystal Reports 10 from 2003. I don't have access to the CR version number on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are different versions of the CR Runtime or Crystal Reports it could be due to the report using a feature that is not supported in the lower version of the two.  For example, I develop in CR 2016, but our ERP system uses an older version of the CR Runtime.  CR 2016 allows me to vertically align text as top, center, or bottom; but running reports from the ERP system always uses bottom align because the runtime doesn't support vertical alignment.

Check your margin settings on your report.  You may be running into issues with how one version supports minimum margins differently than the other.  If the report has a value of 0 for any of the margins, you may need to increase it to a minimum value or .25 or .5 inches.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I checked it out, and the margins are the same for both prints. My guess now is that the one on the left was done using a NEWER version of Crystal Reports. CR10 is from 2003, and someone with a newer version is trying to help me. I did notice that the pdf on the right is 61kb, and the one on the left is 65kb. Is there any option in the newer version that would add slightly more space? I'd say it's about 1mm off on each line, resulting in slightly too much text displacement.

Comment: It may be worth your time to reach out to SAP on this issue.  They would have the expertise to better know all of the differences between two versions.  I've also seen some things on their support forums about registry fixes that be used to force solutions for problems similar to yours, but I think you will need one of their support specialists to help you identify which, if any, registry fixes might help you.